# Mysql запрос к 2-м таблицам не проходит

Tags: php, mysql

Есть зависимые `select` поля для выбора марки и моделей авто.

Запрос делаю так, но он выводит только модели из БД, а марки нет, как исправить?

Таблица `mark` содержит поля `id`, `title` (название марки)

Таблица `model` содержит поля `id`. `mark_id`, `title` (модели)

При совпадении полей таблицы `mark.id` и `model.mark_id` нужно чтобы выводились все совпадения моделей из `model.title`

Пробовал так.

```
$marks = R::findAll('mark', 'ORDER BY title ASC');    
        $model = R::findAll('model', 'ORDER BY title ASC');
```

И так.

```
SELECT
  mark.id, 
  mark.title, 
  mark.title AS mark,
  model.title AS model
FROM mark
   INNER JOIN mark ON mark.id = model.mark_id
   INNER JOIN model ON model.mark_id = model
LEFT JOIN rent_photo ON rent.id = rent_photo.rent_id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предыдущий комментатор был практически прав.

Но у него была ошибка с одним полем таблицы model, вместо `name` у Vovvka стоит `title`.

```
$model = R::getAssoc('SELECT model.id, model.title AS model,mark.title AS Mark
FROM model
INNER JOIN mark
ON model.mark_id = mark.id');
```

Укажите на странице проверку `print_r($model);`

У вас должны выйти на страницу все марки и модели по ключам.

Comment: Спасибо!!! Теперь выводит модели в списке print_r($model);  ,  но вопрос с зависимыми списками марка-модель все еще не решен...

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE mark
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    title VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
 
CREATE TABLE model
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    mark_id INT,
    name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (mark_id) REFERENCES mark(Id)
);


SELECT model.id, model.name AS Model,mark.title AS Mark
FROM model
INNER JOIN mark
ON model.mark_id = mark.id;
```

OUTPUT

```
+----+----------+--------+
| id | Model    | Mark   |
+----+----------+--------+
|  1 | X5       | BMW    |
|  2 | X4       | BMW    |
|  3 | camry    | Toyota |
|  4 | Ravon r3 | Nexia  |
|  5 | Ravon r4 | Nexia  |
|  6 | Ravon r2 | Nexia  |
+----+----------+--------+
```

Рекомнедую посетить [Joins in sql](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) и изуть детальнее

Comment: спасибо за подсказку и код, к сожалению сейчас его попробовал внедрить на зависимых списках, марки выводит, модели как и прежде нет.

Comment: можете показать как вы имплементировали и где. Может смогу помочь решить проблему

Comment: Буду очень благодарен, 2 недели с данным вопросом мучаюсь. Вот ссылка где создана эта тема с описанием JS https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1190929/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4